# Calling a PowerShell script from a batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to run a PowerShell script from a batch file, and it runs successfully on my machine. However when I put it on the server, it throws this error:

> "Missing expression after unary operator '-'. 
>   At line:1 char:2 
>   + -E <<<< xecutionPolicy remotesigned -file 'E:\Misdemeanor  
> Queue\Concatenate.ps1'

I've tried different combinations of the execution policy, but nothing seems to work. I have to run this on Windows Server 2003, SP2, and it uses v1.0 of PowerShell (which is what I wrote this in). There is a space in the folder name that houses the batch file & ps1 file. Here is the batch file that calls the ps1 file named Concatenate.ps1:

```
 - @echo off &setlocal
del "E:\Misdemeanor Queue\Index3.txt"
set "search=.tif"
set "replace=|"
set "textfile=index2.txt"
set "newfile=Index3.txt"

(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr "^" "%textfile%"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"%newfile%"
type "%newfile%"


PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& 'E:\Misdemeanor Queue\Concatenate.ps1'"
```

---

Here is the concatenate.ps1 file:

> $File1 = Get-Content "E:\Misdemeanor Queue\Index3.txt" $File2 =
>   Get-Content "E:\Misdemeanor Queue\index1.txt" $File3 = @()
>   For($a=0;$a -lt $File1.count;$a++){
>   $File3+=$File1[$a].trim()+$File2[$a].trim() } $File3 | Out-File
>   "E:\Misdemeanor Queue\indexFINAL.txt"

---

It's supposed to call this ps file, concatenate the Index3 file and the Index1 file, and create a txt file called indexFINAL.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the error you would get on PowerShell 1.0 where the `-ExecutionPolicy` parameter is not supported.  So I suspect your server has version 1.0 installed.  If a PowerShell prompt comes up with a copyright date of 2006 then it is version 1.0.  Can you upgrade the server to at least v2 to get support for that parameter?

Comment: I've looked into PS v 2.0 and it seems I would have to have at least Server2008 installed - our server is running 2003 SP2. Is there any way around this? You mean, you cannot run PowerShell v1 on a server?

Comment: You can run scripts on PowerShell V1 on your server. You just can't set the execution policy at the time you execute your script.  You have to set that separately.  Pull up a PowerShell prompt on that server and run `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`.  Then try your script again without the `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` parameter and argument.